# error TS2769: No overload matches this call. (error is in task-view.component.ts) line= .subscribe((lists: List[]) => this.lists = lists);

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mean-stack

```
error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: NextObserver<Object> | ErrorObserver<Object> | CompletionObserver<Object> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.     
    Argument of type '(lists: List[]) => List[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextObserver<Object> | ErrorObserver<Object> | CompletionObserver<Object> | 
undefined'.
      Property 'complete' is missing in type '(lists: List[]) => List[]' but required in type 'CompletionObserver<Object>'.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(lists: List[]) => List[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'lists' and 'value' are incompatible.
        The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
          Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'List[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

20       .subscribe((lists: List[]) => this.lists = lists);
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts:73:5
    73     complete: () => void;
           ~~~~~~~~
    'complete' is declared here.
```

**task-view.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import List from 'src/app/models/list';
import Task from 'src/app/models/task';
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/task.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-view',
  templateUrl: './task-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-view.component.scss'],
})
export class TaskViewComponent implements OnInit {
  lists: List[] = [];
  tasks: Task[] = [];

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.taskService
      .getLists()
      .subscribe((lists: List[]) => this.lists = lists);
  }
}
```

**task.service.ts**

```
import { WebService } from './web.service';
import Task from './models/task'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TaskService {
  constructor(private webService: WebService) {}
  getLists() {
    return this.webService.get('lists');
  }

  createList(title: string) {
    return this.webService.post('lists', { title });
  }

  getTasks(listId: string) {
    return this.webService.get(`lists/${listId}/tasks`);
  }

  createTasks(listId: string, title: string) {
    return this.webService.post(`lists/${listId}/tasks`, { title });
  }

  deleteList(listId: string) {
    return this.webService.delete(`lists/${listId}`);
  }

  deleteTask(listId: string, taskId: string) {
    return this.webService.delete(`lists/${listId}/tasks/${taskId}`);
  }

  setCompleted(listId: string, task: Task ) {
    return this.webService.patch(`lists/${listId}/tasks/${task._id}`, {completed: !task.completed});
  }
}
```

**web.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebService {
  readonly ROOT_URL;
  constructor( private http: HttpClient) {
    this.ROOT_URL = "http://localhost:3000" ;
   }

   get(uri: string) {
     return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/$(uri)`);
   }

   post(uri: string, payload: Object) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.ROOT_URL}/$(uri)`, payload );
  }

  patch(uri: string, payload: Object) {
    return this.http.patch(`${this.ROOT_URL}/$(uri)`, payload );
  }

  delete(uri: string) {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.ROOT_URL}/$(uri)`);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `$(uri)` should be `${uri}`

Comment: @eko not worked, error is in task-view.component.ts

Comment: What happens if you typecast your http.get? --e.g: `this.http.get<List[]>(\`${this.ROOT_URL}/$(uri)\`)`

Comment: is this issue resolved?

Comment: @eko your 1st answer worked ${uri}. thanks lot

Comment: @eko, also i will appreciate your help in another issue in my app, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67688442/angular-gettask-api-is-not-getting-data-from-backend-no-error-is-thrown-just

Comment: Ok let me provide the answer for this first :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For string interpolation you should use `${uri}` instead of `$(uri)`

Answer (score 0):

If still, you have that error, you can try:

```
this.taskService.getLists().subscribe((lists:any) => this.lists = lists);
```

Instead of:

```
this.taskService.getLists().subscribe((lists:List[]) => this.lists = lists);
```